# reportLab showPage() doesn't work on landscape layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I'm trying create a pdf with many pages, it work 100% with portrait ones, but if i try create a portrait pdf, the showPage() function doesn't create a new page.

It's my code with landscape layout:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("C:/Report.pdf",pagesize=Landscape(A4)

for i in range(5):
    c.drawString(100,750,'test')
    c.showPage()
c.save()
```

And here is my code in portrait layout:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("C:/Report.pdf",pagesize=A4

for i in range(5):
    c.drawString(100,750,'test')
    c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine (after fixing the typos).  It creates 5 blank pages.  The pages are blank because you are writing the text off the top of the page.  The top edge of an A4 landscape page is 597 points.

Comment: Here, at landscape, it creates only 1 page "/

EDIT: now that i've tested, it works e.e holy, ty anyway